# mysql - how to select from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables.

1. servers: With details about the server. Relevant columns are: id, name
2. actions: With action about a specific server. Relevant columns are: fdate, server_id, status

I want to get the names of the server so that their last line in the actions table is NOT OK.

First, I select the last inserted line with the status is NOTOK from action:

```
SELECT t1.server_id, 
       t1.status 
FROM actions t1 
WHERE t1.fdate = (SELECT MAX(t2.fdate) 
                  FROM actions t2 
                  WHERE t2.server_id = t1.server_id ) 
  AND status = "NOTOK";
```

| server_id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 762 | NOTOK |
| 1304 | NOTOK |

Now I want to get from the servers table the name of the server so I did:

```
SELECT t1.server_id, 
       t3.name 
FROM      actions t1 
LEFT JOIN servers t3 
       ON t3.id = t1.server_id 
      AND t1.fdate = (SELECT MAX(t2.fdate) 
                      FROM actions t2 
                      WHERE t2.server_id = t1.server_id ) 
      AND t1.status = "NOTOK" and t3.name is not null;
```

I got:

| server_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 762 | NULL |
| 762 | NULL |
| 762 | server1 |
| 1304 | NULL |
| 1304 | NULL |
| 1304 | server3 |

How can I get only the relevant lines that contain server1 and server3?

In the column name have content it's shown as null only in the JOIN above. How can I check if the output  of the JOIN is not null

servers:

| id | name | description | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 762 | server1 | description1 | OK |
| 1304 | server3 | description2 | OK |

actions:

| id | server_id | name | details | fdate | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 227 | 762 | probem1 | problem 1 details | 2022-08-03 11:53:29 | NOTOK |
| 230 | 762 | probem2 | problem 2 details | 2022-08-03 11:54:02 | NOTOK |
| 233 | 762 | solve | solve | 2022-08-03 11:55:53 | NOTOK |
| 236 | 1304 | gsdfg | gdsf | 2022-08-03 11:58:12 | NOTOK |
| 239 | 1304 | gdfgfd | gsdfgfds | 2022-08-03 11:58:16 | NOTOK |
| 242 | 1304 | ghfg | hfg | 2022-08-03 12:33:08 | NOTOK |

Comment: Can you share sample input tables of "*servers*" and "*actions*"?

Comment: can you try name is not null?

Comment: I edit the question &  answer  your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN and got

| server_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 762 | server1 |
| 1304 | server3 |

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a Where clause

```
Where name is not null
```